# collection findOne is returning undefiend

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor client code is expected to return one document which works fine on the server console. 
`db.validationCol.findOne({'key':'myname'});`

But returns undefiend on the client. How can it be fixed? Thanks

```js
// server
ValidationCol = new Mongo.Collection('validationCol');

Meteor.publish('validationCol', function () {
  return ValidationCol.find({});
});

(function () {
  const docs = {
    myname: '^[0-9a-zA-Z]{65}$'
  };
  for (let property in docs) {
    if (docs.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      ValidationCol.insert({key: property, regex: docs[property]});
     }
  }
})();

//client
let key = 'myname'
      let regex = ValidationCol.findOne({key: key});
      console.log(regex);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe inside your client code:

```
ValidationCol = new Mongo.Collection('validationCol');

Meteor.publish('validationCol', function () {
  return ValidationCol.find({});
});

(function () {
  const docs = {
    myname: '^[0-9a-zA-Z]{65}$'
  };
  for (let property in docs) {
    if (docs.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      ValidationCol.insert({key: property, regex: docs[property]});
     }
  }
})();

//client
let key = 'myname'
// Subscription
Meteor.subscribe('validationCol');
let regex = ValidationCol.findOne({key: key});
console.log(regex);
```